# Getting error while calling web services after SSL certificate renewal?

Tags: web-services, binding, ssl-certificate, iis-8

I am using webservice in my .NET based application.The web services are called from control M job which connects to our server where B2B services are hosted and files are fetched. Recently the link between interface and webs service was broken. When I tried to hit the web service in our browser it gave error as SSL certificate got expired.But the website was working fine without any certificate error, and the only certificate bound in the server was not expired. We renewed the certificate and bound it again in IIS, but then we were not able to hit the web service and getting the error page not found. Can anyone tell the reason for it?

Comment: Do you have any error logs that come up when you hit your endpoint? Look at event viewer to see if you can see anything. This is a stab in the dark but when you created your new cert, does it have the correct common names and DNS names as your old certificate?

Comment: No we didn't get any error, I am curious to know how did the certificate expired only for B2B services not for website,as both are hosted on same server.

Comment: I would try to create the error again, bind the B2B service, to an invalid cert. just create a self-signed cert that is expired and with the incorrect common name and dns name